# How to get a and b value back from a inner function

Tags: python

I have a small question in python. Given this def:

**Code:**

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair
```

Is there a way to return the a and b value of challenge So for instance `returnA(cons(a, b))` should return `a`. Does anybody has a clue how to do this?

Comment: Could you expand on your explanation of what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, im trying to solve small challanges and I have tried anything with this, but I just cannot figure out how I am able to return A or B when I created a pair. Because the def returns a function instead of a object.

Comment: when you call `pair` you need to pass it a value for `f`

Comment: Please update the indentation in the last line. What is `returnA`?

Comment: Sorry for being this unclear, I will format my question better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cons` returns a function that will call a function you pass to it with arguments, `a` and `b` captured in the closure. You need to pass a function into `cons`'s return value that does what you want. If you just want to return the values you cans something like:

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair

f = cons(2, 3)
a, b, = f(lambda x, y: (x, y)) # (2, 3)

# or
f(print) # prints 2, 3
```

Comment: Thanks to you, this was what I meant.